SVN / SASL authentication error: failed to init cipher 'rc4'
im trying to update an old project via SVN and get this:
SASL authentication error: SASL(-1): generic failure: internal error: failed to init cipher 'rc4'

openssl tells me RC4 is disabled by default and google says it would be a bad idea to enabled it.
on both (client and server) i get same ciphers for ssl (should be default):
> openssl ciphers -s
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA

it looks like a config issue to me but openssl.cnf, subversion/config and .subversion/config (on client) is default, i didnt touched it.
so i guess it could be something with SASL but i cant find it out. maybe i messed up configs while trying to set up mail with exim4 and dovecot instead of postfix (but thats a different story). anyway i sure svn worked after this.
pls help me.
Client versions:
6.6.65-1-MANJARO
svn, Version 1.14.4 (r1920901)
OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024)

Server:
Debian GNU/Linux 12
svn, Version 1.14.2 (r1899510)
libsasl2-2 (2.1.28+dfsg-10)
OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024)

[EDIT]
svnserve.cfg (on server)
[sasl]
use-sasl = true
min-encryption = 128
max-encryption = 512

[if i change min-encryption to 256 or higher i get a different error msg:
E170001: Could not obtain the list of SASL mechanisms.
cf. https://superuser.com/questions/759241/how-to-configure-sasl-with-subversion]

The server part show the version of the SVN client, not the server. What's the version of the server (httpd, mod_dav_svn), what OpenSSL version its built with? What's in httpd.conf?

do you mean apache? I dont have any svn directives in my apache config and afaik I never had one. I config svn via svnadmin and run it by svnserve

To be sure you realize: SASL and SSL (now really TLS) are separate and different protocols, although both can use primitives from the libcrypto part of OpenSSL, though AFAICT libsasl doesn't. openssl ciphers lists ciphersuites used for SSL/TLS in libssl and has no connection at all to SASL. openssl list, particularly openssl list -cipher-algorithms, tells you things libcrypto can do.

I know the chain SVN, SASL, SSL - theoretical, but not practical. So who in the chain limits ciphers to 128 bit and/or RC4? How to see it and how to config it?
